# Generate multiple pages from a one page template?

Tags: multicol

I am working on a daily journal, so most things will be the same everyday, except some small things like a date. I have made the first page, and everything looks how I want it to.
How I want to be able to use that first page as a template, and generate lets say 10 pages, each with their own date.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Our magic crystal ball says: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. First guess: Put the page content in a macro with date as the macro argument. Perhaps the `multicol` tag is wrong here, but let's see

Comment: You accepted my answer, but it would have been nice to know how helpful the answer was/which features it should have had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rudimentary proposition, without much effort and *smart* stuff

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\journal}{+m+m}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Date: #1},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=black]
Captain's log, stardate #1
\tcblower
#2
\end{tcolorbox}%
\clearpage
}


\begin{document}

% Doing ten (identical entries, apart from the date
\foreach \x in {0,...,9} {%
  \AdvanceDate[\x]
  \journal{\today}{%
    This day...
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]